# how to do multidimensional array intersection using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am doing an array intersection in javascript using **lodash**, the below is the code that i am trying, what i am getting is

```
["universal", "ola", "uber", "bangalore"],
```

But, what i am expecting is 
["universal"]

Here, the **orgArr** multidiemensional array with n numbers of items, i mean, the **orgArr** can have 5 or 6 or 10 items... example

```
[["garden","canons","philips","universal"],["universal","ola","uber","bangalore"], ["ola","uber","bangalore"]];
```

**It is not just with two items please note**

```
var orgArr = [["garden","canons","philips","universal"],["universal","ola","uber","bangalore"]];
    var resfinaArray = [];


    for (var i = 0; i < orgArr.length; i++){
         var currItem = orgArr[i];

         for (var j = 0; j< orgArr.length; j++){

         resfinaArray.push(_.intersection(currItem, orgArr[j]));
         }
    }

    console.log(resfinaArray, 'resfinaArray');
```

Any help please?

Comment: isnt this supposed to be just `var resfinaArray = _intersection(['garden','canons','philips','universal'],['universal', 'uber', 'bangalore']);`

Comment: @apieceofbart Exactly. The `for` loops are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `forEach()` loop and optional `thisArg` parameter.

```js
var orgArr = [["garden","canons","philips","universal"],["universal","ola","uber","bangalore"]];
var resfinaArray = [];

orgArr.forEach(function(a) {
  var that = this;
  a.forEach(function(e) {
    (!that[e]) ? that[e] = true : resfinaArray.push(e);
  })
}, {});

console.log(resfinaArray);
```

Comment: yours is working only for two items, it should work with extra times as well if there is any

Comment: your jsfiddle works fine but still there is some flaws. it is pushing duplicate items as well on resfinaArray.  try this var orgArr = [["garden","canons","philips","universal"],["universal","ola","uber","bangalore","philips"],["bangalore","philips"],["universal","ola","uber","bangalore"]];

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var array = [["garden", "canons", "philips", "universal"], ["universal", "ola", "uber", "bangalore"], ["abc", "def", "universal"]],
    result = [...array.reduce((r, a, i) => 
        a.reduce((s, b) =>
            (!i || r.has(b)) && s.add(b) || s, new Set), new Set)];
   
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this job as follows;

```js
var intersectArrays = a => a.reduce((p,c) => p.filter(e => c.includes(e))),
                arr = [["garden","canons","philips","universal"],["universal","ola","uber","bangalore"], ["ola","uber","bangalore", "universal"]],
                brr = intersectArrays(arr);
console.log(brr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops:

```
var intersection = _.intersection(["garden","canons","philips","universal"],["universal","ola","uber","bangalore"]);
```

In case you have your data in array you can use `apply`:

```
var intersection = _.intersection.apply(null, [["garden","canons","philips","universal"],["universal","ola","uber","bangalore"]]);
```